# Delete unnecessary files from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Android Studio is taking up more than 16GB of space.
I would like to delete some files.
I use my cell phone to compile the code.
So I would like to delete all files that are related to AVD.

System-Images take up nearly 12GB.
I believe system-images are used for rendering AVDs.
So can I just delete them?
Is there a particular method by which they have to be deleted?

I am not programming for either Android Wear or TV.
I also don't have an Intel processor (I have AMD).
So what files & folders can I delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously delete anything that says Intel since you can't run it with AMD. You only need one system image and SDK for each API you need to test against. Delete everything else. ... Or, just delete everything. Start from scratch. Try to run things, then install the bare minimum of what you think you need as the errors occur.

Also, your phone runs the code, not compiles... Anyways, if that is the case, delete all system images. Leave the APIs that you need. If you are not developing offline, then delete the Documentation & Sources as well.

Use the SDK Manager for all this

I like to keep in minimal. Last time I checked, it was around 600 MB

[image]

Comment: I checked ARM stands for ARM Emulator... shouldn't I delete it as I am not using AVD?

Comment: ARM is an [instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture). Compared to x86, but that's besides the point. Yes, you are using your phone to run code, then no need for an system images, as those are for the AVD

Comment: @suku My Android folder is only 600Mb... I have maybe 4 API versions "SDK Platform", then only the latest build-tools, documentation, support libraries, etc.

Comment: That's awesome..Can you put a screenshot of your sdk manager showing the installed packages? Do you delete old "Android SDK Build-Tools" and "SDK Platforms"?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For each API you want to build for, you should keep the SDK platform, Google APIs and Sources for Android SDK. Samples are nice but not necessary.

I wouldn't touch the first `tools` folder. Everything else you can uncheck and delete.

I have all those installed for API 17, 19, 21, 23 and my SDK folder comes to ~6.5 gbs

Comment: thanks :) Upvoted your answer...Got mine down to less than 6GB

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldnt be manually deleting files from the /sdk folder (since you're talking about system images and intel).

Use the `SDK Manager` to uninstall the components you don't need. It should have the system images and other components you mentioned listed as `installed`.